# Duplicate rows in dataframe and add 1 value in a different field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Junior dev here.

**Goal:**
Implement a second autogenerated row with one of the projects prefilled out. The first row is blank.

[image: Desired Output]

**Requirements:**

- The first row of each resource will remain blank.
- The second row will have a pre-generated project name called "Admin".
- The rows of each resource must be next to each other.
- Sort the "Name" row by ASC order.
- This must be applied to the entire dataset (~900 resources, demo df created for illustration of assistance).

I think I have to do something with a lamda function but I'm not clear on how to fill only 1 row from each resource.

**Current Output:**
I have the table in a pandas Dataframe. The console output is what I have currently.

[image: Current Output]

Here's what I have in the script.

```
import pandas as pd
# Demo DF only
df1 = {
        'Name': ['Julia', 'David'],
        'Project': ['',''],
        'Task': ['',''],
        'Hours': ['','']
      }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['Name', 'Project', 'Task','Hours'])
df1 = df1.assign(Project="Admin")
df_repeated = pd.concat([df1]*2, ignore_index=True)
df_repeated = df_repeated.sort_values(by=['Name'], ascending=True)
print(df_repeated)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df1, df1.assign(Project="Admin")],
          ignore_index=True).sort_values(["Name", "Project"])
#     Name Project Task Hours
# 1  David                   
# 3  David   Admin           
# 0  Julia                   
# 2  Julia   Admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy's function "[where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)" to either add the "Admin" in every other row:

```python
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df_repeated = pd.concat([df1]*2, ignore_index=True)
df_repeated = df_repeated.sort_values(by=['Name'], ascending=True, ignore_index=True)
df_repeated['Project'] = np.where(df_repeated.index % 2, 'Admin', '')
```